# Can you put a detuner on any string of a 5 string bass

Tags: tuning, 5-string-bass-guitar

I have a spector euro 5 string bass and I wanna know if there is a way to put a hipshot or some other kind of detuner on my E string. I can hit all my notes with the the low string, just somethings move smoother in drop D.

Answer (score 1):

There are machine heads on the market that look like they'll match yours. The problem may be the space between the A and B string machine heads. Best is to contact the manufacturers of both the heads and the bass, and ask the question there.